# Tufte_Latex Itemize or Enumerate inside Caption does not compile

Tags: captions, itemize, tufte

The Itemize/enumerate environment works flawlessly within Latex (eg report class). It did also compile fine a couple of years ago despite throwing up some warnings using the {tufte-book} class. Not any more. Appears to be a tufte book class specific problem.
The singlelincheck=off does not make a difference.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, justified]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

  \caption[shortcaption]{Caption blah blah
   
\begin{enumerate}[a)]
\item blah
\item blah blah
\end{enumerate}
}

\label{fig: blah}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

--- TeX said ---
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 438.
--- HELP ---
No help available

Comment: What's the purpose of an `enumerate` environment inside of a `\caption`?

Comment: figures that require a caption listing the items represented in a formatted way. not uncommon judging by similar questions. any ideas?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: Your MWE runs without **error** on an up to date TeX Live installation

Comment: I have re run the MWE and indeed it now runs. However, the figure label is on the right (as expected) and the caption is now under the figure and not, as expected, to the right with the label. The short caption is printed (not expected) with the label.

Comment: Anyway, the package `caption` is not compatible with `tufte`

Comment: Thats why then. Ta.

Comment: Hm, edited the MWE without caption package. Does not compile.